# Clear related items followed by parent entity update - Many to Many EntityFramework with AutoMapper

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, many-to-many, automapper

I am trying to remove all references followed by adding them back from a list of disconnected objects.

```
using(var scope  = new TransactionScope())
{
    _autoIncidentService.AddNewCompanyVehicles(
        autoIncidentModel.CompanyVehiclesInvolved.Where(v => v.Id == 0));
    _autoIncidentService.ClearCollections(autoIncidentModel.Id);
    _autoIncidentService.Update(autoIncidentModel);

    scope.Complete();
}
return Json(ResponseView);
```

The **ClearCollections** removes items references. The **GetAutoIncident** includes the collection.

```
public void ClearCollections(int id)
{
    var autoIncident = GetAutoIncident(id);
    foreach (var vehicle in autoIncident.CompanyVehiclesInvolved.ToArray())
    {
        autoIncident.CompanyVehiclesInvolved.Remove(vehicle);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I try to update the entity right after the **ClearCollections** method it fails.

*The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.*

I am using a singleton to get the DbContext so there shouldn't be any situation where the context is different. It is being stored in the HttpContext.Current.Items.

The update method is as follows:

```
public override void Update(AutoIncidentModel model)
{
    var data = GetData(model.Id);
    Mapper.CreateMap<AutoIncidentModel, AutoIncident>()
        .ForMember(m => m.CompanyVehiclesInvolved, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(m =>
        {
            var ids = m.CompanyVehiclesInvolved.Select(v => v.Id);
            return db.Vehicles.Where(v => ids.Contains(v.Id)).ToList();
        }));
    Mapper.Map(model, data);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Obviously, I am missing something important here. Do the entites from my ResolveUsing method need to somehow be associated with the parent entity or is automapper overwriting the property (CompanyVehiclesInvolved) and causing a problem?

Comment: The exception pretty clearly tells what's wrong. What's your question?

Comment: I have a singleton for my DbContext so it isn't really clear to me what is going wrong here.